# No sound after RAM upgrade

Tags: audio, memory, upgrade, hp-laptop

When I upgrade my RAM (DDR2) on an old HP 6730s laptop from 1x2GB to 2x2GB my sound will stop working (W10).
I was able to get exactly the same DDR2 card, hoping that all frequencies, timing and everything will match, but apparently NO. Laptop should support up to 8GB, any ideas what might be wrong, what am I missing, that those cards are not compatible?

Cards:
Samsung 2GB 2Rx8 PC2-6400S-666-12-E3, M470T5663EH3-CF7

**Edit I:**

- Sounds is not working only when both cards connected, works one by one
- System: W10Pro x64 (verified)

**Edit II:**

- Device manager shows same values for soundcard with 1 and 2 cards
- Unplugged battery does not help

**Edit III:**

- **I tried to boot from Linux USB live distro and the sound is working!**
- Tried the first restore point after clean W10 installation, nothing, could it be the system wrong installation?

Comment: If you remove the memory you added, does the sound work? If it doesn’t then your lose of sound has nothing to do with the memory upgrade

Comment: Is the soundcard built in? Do you have a 64 bit version of Windows? I vaguely remember some ancient soundblaster cards didn't have proper drivers or hardware support for systems with >2GB RAM and had some trouble with them about 15 years ago...

Comment: The sound does not work only when both cards are plugged in, one by one works. Probably build in, 64bit Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: @Popkornak please edit your question with the additional info *"...one by one works...."* this is valuable info.

Comment: @Popkornak - We need verified information.  Please [edit] your question after you have verified if you are running a 64-bit version of Windows. I would be shocked if you were due to the age of your system and the fact the 64-bit version of Windows 10 requires more than 2 GB of memory to even install.

Comment: built in soundcard. Windows is truly x64, which I newly installed on that device. RAM upgrade should have been part of it.

Comment: What info does it show in device manager for the sound (with and without the added RAM)?

Comment: I'm thinking of it's a power issue where the motherboard doesn't have enough juice to power both the added RAM and the soundcard.

Comment: Device manager shows the same values with 1card or 2cards. Also tried power it up directly, without battery - no change.

Comment: The same, but what info does it show? I want to know the soundcard info.

Comment: Can you please specify what device information I am looking for? Both scenarios the soundcard devices are present, no warning, no exclamation mark.

Comment: The name and model of the soundcard, and driver version

Comment: `High Definition Audi Device` | `hdaudio\func_01&ven_11d4&dev_194a&subsys_103c3614` | Driver `10.0.19041.264` (09.05.2020), I tried like 15 times to change the drivers, there are 2 available but no works. This was my original thought that its not working because of the drivers. Also update the question with EDIT 3, - sound is working under Linux Live distro.